# Jasper Domain Query Language

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am using iReport to build reports against a domain I've created on JasperServer. When building the report Jasper creates a domain query in XML, based on what fields and filters you've chosen in the GUI. But iReport also gives you the facility to manually edit the query (like you can with SQL queries, and other languages)

I'd like to know more about what else you can specify in the query language xml. For example, I know that there is an 'expression' attribute on the  element but I'm not aware of what types of expressions you are allowed to specify in there.

Can anybody point me to any documentation on what commands/elements/attributes are availabe in domain query language.

Thanks

example of the query language format:

```
<query xmlns="http://www.jaspersoft.com/2007/SL/XMLSchema">
  <queryFields>
    <queryField id="PM.SupplierDetails.CodeandName" />
    <queryField id="PurchaseLedger.Transactions.AmountPaid" />
  </queryFields>
</query><queryfilterstring>...</queryfilterstring>
```

Comment: Did you find more information on the Domain Query Language?

Comment: Yes but more by trial and error through trying things and debugging the source code. Documentation has slightly improved in this area if you look at the JasperReports Server documentation.

Comment: Could you please let me know how you introduced the SQL "GROUP BY" clause in "queryfilterstring" ? eg: SELECT COLUMN1,COUNT(COLUMN2) from TABLE group by COLUMN1

Comment: I don't think you can implement 'group by' in this way.
I take it the reason you're asking to do group by's is for aggregation, summing, etc.. on a particular column. If so, you can use SQL partitioning for this 
eg 1
 rank() over ( order by some_value )
eg 2
sum( value_to_sum ) over ( partition by col_used_grouping_by )

These can then be used in calculated fields in domains, or can be specified as a DomEL function (see JasperReports Server documentation for doing this)

btw this is really a separate query

Answer (score 0):

It seems that iReport does not yet support domain based query languages. Check [this](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport/tracker/view.php?id=5063).

Comment: I think you misunderstand the issue in the link you have provided. All this is saying is that you cannot run reports that use a domain datasource _locally_ on iReport. You have to save them as a report unit on the server first and then run them on the remote server.